# Setting href attribute in IE without changing link appearance without setting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

IE has a problem that if I for example try dynamically change a link like:

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com">www.foo.com</a>
```

To

```
<a href="http://www.bar.com?q=www.foo.com">www.foo.com</a>
```

Using JavaScript the link is changed (in IE only) to

```
<a href="http://www.bar.com?q=www.foo.com">http://www.bar.com?q=www.foo.com</a>
```

Which isn't what I'm trying to do.

I had found solutions like save innterHTML, change link and restore the innterHTML 
with the old value... But what if the inner content has some dynamically attached
events? The will be lost.

Currently I try to check if there any HTML attribute withing innerHTML, and if not I restore
the old HTML.

```
function change_link(a,newlink)
{
    if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var old = a.innerHTML ;
        if(old.indexOf('<')==-1) {
            a.href=newlink;
            a.innerHTML = old;
            return
        }
    }
    a.href=newlink;
}
```

May there be any problems with it?

Can an event be attached to the plain text of the inner HTML dynamically and it will be lost during innerHTML reset?

Comment: Internet Explorer does not actually do that, I don't think.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if this was something IE is doing as an anti-phishing mechanism (not allowing a URL content that mismatches the href). Maybe you could try leaving the href intact and trap the onclick event instead?

Comment: You shouldn't have to work around something that shouldn't be happening.  Can you post the original code you're having issues with?

Comment: @PhonicUK but `<a>` tag text mismatches the "href" value *all the time*.

Comment: @Pointy, I'm talking about the specific case where the content is also a URL instead of arbitrary text.

Comment: have you tried it with attribute .attr("href", "")

Comment: Yes I thought about that ... I can't try it because my VirtualBox is hosed up but you may be right (still think it's questionable behavior but whatever).

Comment: @PhonicUK [looks like you were exactly right](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4125) (There's a simple workaround in that bug report.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790698/javascript-workaround-needed-internet-explorer-changes-link-text-when-changing

Comment: I'd also try using character entities in the URL, that may bypass the problem without requiring logic.

Comment: @MattWhipple it does it... I had found some reference about it and I had't invented the innterHTML method. However changing innerHTML has its own drawbacks - because it may remove all attached events. That what I'm trying to prevent

Comment: Events attached to what?  You should only be operating on the text child/content of the link and it _may_ be possible but it would be highly unusual and unnecessary to have an event attached to that. The workaround that @Pointy mentions above should take care of it with less work than the innerHTML fix.  I'd also suggest using a `span` inside of the `a` which would require very slight logic modification but may smell slightly less than the workaround it it works.